# How to handle fallback intent in RASA NLU by setting a threshold value

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to build an application in RASA NLU where I want to route all not understood text to the None Intent.

But, if I give some gibberish text, it's not giving the none intent instead its giving me some other intent.

> My questions are:
>
> 1. How do I set a threshold value for None Intent, such that if
>      confidence score is below that it will fallback to the None Intent.
> 2. Why is it routing to another intent instead of None intent when I'm
>      giving gibberish input?

Answer (score 4):

There are three different methods of handling these sorts of unexpected inputs from the user. We will implement them in this order:

1. **Design to minimize fallbacks** — We will start by adding in more
   intents.
2. **Collect the Garbage** — We will train a special intent to collect the
   garbage.
3. **Handle Confusion with Confidence** — We will add logic to handle low
   confidence Classifications.

Check out this blog post for detailed solution.
https://blog.spg.ai/failing-gracefully-with-rasa-nlu-14a7d8e53af9

Comment: hi 
can you help me out ,i have a large data set which is round 12689 and i have trained it successfully but for every intent example i am getting the response blank which is considered as the nlu_fallback.

Comment: while the chatbot is giving the correct answers and responses for the small data set where my nlu file has around 900 lines